# Why is boost::program_options accepting chopped words?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I have the following program:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

bool check_options(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using namespace boost::program_options;
    variables_map vm;

    // Command line options
    std::string cfg_file_name;
    options_description cmd_line("Allowed options");
    cmd_line.add_options()
        ("help", "produce this help message")
        ;

    store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, cmd_line), vm);
    notify(vm);    
    if(vm.count("help")) 
    {
        std::cout << cmd_line << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(!check_options(argc, argv))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it with `./myprg --help` I get the result I expect:

```
Allowed options:
  --help                produce this help message
```

However I get the same result even if I run: `./myprg --h` or `./myprg --he` or `./myprg --hel`. Shouldn't those last options throw an error?

Comment: Seems like that is the "default style". See this post at the Boost site http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2007/02/25861.php

Comment: yup that's it! If you write an answer posting that link I'll accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like accepting partial matches is the `default_style` for `boost::option`.

According to an answer at the Boost site http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2007/02/25861.php

this default can be changed to require a full match, by passing an extra parameter to `parse_command_line`.

EDIT by OP:
Actually instead of `parse_command_line` I had to use the more general `command_line_parser` (which allows style changings), thus replacing the `store(...` line with this one:

```
store(command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(cmd_line).style(command_line_style::default_style & ~command_line_style::allow_guessing).run(), vm);
```